# Keras model.train_on_batch crashes my kernel but model.fit does not, even though my input is smaller with train_on_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am training a convolutional neural network with Keras and the Tensorflow backend on a list of sequences of DNA to predict some of their features. I have two networks set up:

1. pads the beginning of my one-hot encoded sequences so that all sequences are the same length, meaning I can pass them through all at once using model.fit. This padding is reducing my training data as I cannot mask my input with Conv2D.
2. trains the model sequence by sequence, and does not pad them so that the model takes variable input lengths. I am hoping that this will improve model accuracy but every time I iterate over my list of sequences and call model.train_on_batch, my iPython kernel crashes.

Here is the model where I pass in padded inputs:

```
kernel_length=50
kernel_length2=25
kernel_length3=12
conv_layers=128
hot_dim=5
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length, hot_dim), padding='valid', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], hot_dim, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length2, 1), padding='valid', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], hot_dim, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length3, 1), padding='valid', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], hot_dim, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(35,1), padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy", "mae", "mse"])

model.summary()
```

The model summary returns:

```
    _________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_60 (Conv2D)           (None, 851, 1, 128)       32128     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_58 (Activation)   (None, 851, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_92 (Dropout)         (None, 851, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_61 (Conv2D)           (None, 827, 1, 128)       409728    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_59 (Activation)   (None, 827, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_93 (Dropout)         (None, 827, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_62 (Conv2D)           (None, 816, 1, 128)       196736    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_60 (Activation)   (None, 816, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_94 (Dropout)         (None, 816, 1, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPooling (None, 23, 1, 128)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_16 (Flatten)         (None, 2944)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_69 (Dense)             (None, 128)               376960    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_95 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_70 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_96 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_71 (Dense)             (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_72 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,024,865
Trainable params: 1,024,865
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

My batch model is slightly different as I have to use `GlobalMaxPooling2D`:

```
kernel_length=20
kernel_length2=18
kernel_length3=15
conv_layers=64
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length, 4), padding='valid', input_shape=(None, 4, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length2, 1), padding='valid', input_shape=(None, 4, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(conv_layers, (kernel_length3, 1), padding='valid', input_shape=(None, 4, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy", "mae", "mse"])

model.summary()
```

And the model summary for this is

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, None, 1, 64)       5184      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, None, 1, 64)       73792     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, None, 1, 64)       61504     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, None, 1, 64)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling2d_2 (Glob (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 16)                1040      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 158,113
Trainable params: 158,113
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I can train this model with something like:

```
epochs = 10
for y in range(epochs):
    print(y)
    for x in range(len(x_train)):
        model.train_on_batch(x_train[x], np.array(y_train.iloc[x]).reshape((1,1)), sample_weight=None, class_weight=None)
```

I do not understand why using train_on_batch is crashing my iPython kernel while model.fit is not. model.fit is called on a model with the same number of sequences, and they are all padded which means it has far more parameters to train on than the train_on_batch model.

With model.fit I use a batch size of up to 200 sometimes, whereas the way I train with model.train_on_batch is essentially the same as using a batch size of 1 is it not?

Edit: The error which I get when running in the interpreter is:

```
2019-07-02 18:29:40.689406: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9051 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
    2019-07-02 18:29:51.843913: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:542] Check failed: cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(handle_.get(), elem_type, nd, dims.data(), strides.data()) == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0)batch_descriptor: {count: 1 feature_map_count: 128 spatial: 0 1  value_min: 0.000000 value_max: 0.000000 layout: BatchDepthYX}
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Does it run in the standard Python interpreter?

Comment: @BallpointBen no it does not. I've added the error onto the end of my questio question.